# Python3 F-String Formatting with a Variable width?

Tags: python

I would like to replace "10" in the example below with a variable, but I haven't found any examples that work.

```
print(f'{"|":^10s}')
```

Can you suggest a method to set `x=10`, then have:

```
print(f'{"|":^xs}')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
x = 20

print(f'{"|":^{x}s}')
```

Prints:

```
         |
```